# How i can display this pictures from contacts in xaml?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, contacts

```cs
void _appContacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var result in e.Results)
    {
        var stream = result.GetPicture();

        if (stream != null)
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate that contains the Image control.

Comment: All right. I have this xaml-code <ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

And what next?

Comment: Next step would be to read some online documentation about data templating and data binding to collections. We're not here to teach you step by step how to solve your problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can able to get the picture of the contact using the following code, try this.

```
    Contact con;
    private void contactListBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        con = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedValue as Contact);

        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(con.GetPicture());
        ContactImage.Source = img;
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Downvoters, can you please add your comment why you downvoted my answer? I got the solution and don't know why you downvoted?